# .pptx files bypassing ASP.NET web.config authorization

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a web.config in a directory that restricts access to content based on what roles the user has. For some reason this does not apply to .pptx files, and ONLY .pptx files. I checked the MIME types in IIS and .pptx is listed.

Here is the web.config (not actual roles...)

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="user" />
        <allow roles="sweet_user" />
        <allow roles="super_user" />
        <allow roles="user_with_godlike_powers" />
        ...
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Not only does it have to be registered in IIS, it has to be setup to be processed by ASP.NET (not IIS).  You should confirm how the pptx files are being processed.

Comment: I also have an entry in the httphandlers section of the main web.config. Going by this http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/kb/sitefinity-3-x/how-to-restrict-the-access-to-a-given-folder-for-a-specific-role.aspx

Comment: You should update your question to include your handler, and the version of IIS/ASP.NET you are using.